# Always show vertical scrollviewer and always return to top scrollviewer

Tags: c#, uwp, scrollview

I have a scrollviewer

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer
                Name="questionScroll"
                Grid.Row="0"
                MinHeight="150"
                MaxHeight="200"
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
```

I want the vertical scroll to always be visible and so that the scrollviewer always returns to the top scrollviewer. How do you apply it?

Although I have set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible"`, the vertical scrollbar is not always visible if the mouse is not directed to the scrollviewer

Comment: Try to move that `ScrollViewer` level up in xaml hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

This is the design of the `ScrollViewer`.

Because the scrollbar of the `ScrollViewer` may occlude the contents of the control.

By default, the scrollbar will be hidden when the scrollbar is not used. After set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` it will be smaller  instead of disapear after the scrollbar is not used after time.

Best regards.